# React d3.Select is there any way to do this?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a React topograph graph component utilizing the "react-d3-graph" component and I have been trying for two weeks to figure out how to target a link in the graph with d3.select and cannot make it happen.

The graph is comprised of nodes and links. This is the hierarchy of the HTML output:

```
<g id="graph-id-graph-container-zoomable">

<path class="link" d="M863.7507753180932,316.33500179175303A0,0 0 0,1 992.9208716852238,461.10776577072073" id="asw-lab9306a - nlab5320a" x1="863.7507753180932" x2="992.9208716852238" y1="316.33500179175303" y2="461.10776577072073" style="stroke-width: 4; stroke: rgb(211, 211, 211); opacity: 1; fill: none;"></path>

      <g class="node" cx="808.331973835234" cy="46.111332777044865" id="192.168.1.71" transform="translate(808.331973835234,46.111332777044865)">
    <path cursor="pointer" opacity="0.2" d="M-10.606601717798213,-10.606601717798213h21.213203435596427v21.213203435596427h-21.213203435596427Z" fill="#57a3ff" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
    <text dx="18" dy=".35em" fill="black" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" opacity="0.2">192.168.1.71</text></g>
```

In my component I am able to target the nodes with the following function:

```
nodeSelect(id) {    
  d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-zoomable").selectAll("g[id='" + id + "']").selectAll("path").attr('fill',"red").attr('opacity',"1");  
}
```

Works like a charm. HOWEVER, for the last two weeks I have tried every iteration of d3.select to target a link, to no avail. Here are a couple of my latest efforts:

```
d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-zoomable").selectAll("g").selectAll("path").attr('opacity',"0.2");

d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-zoomable").selectAll("g").selectAll("path.link").attr('opacity',"0.2");

d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-zoomable").selectAll("g").selectAll("path#asw-lab9306a - nlab5320a").attr('opacity',"0.2");
```

Nothing works. This is all housed within a master click function in the component which is programmed as follows:

```
   handleClick = (id) => {
    d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-zoomable").selectAll("g").selectAll("path#asw-lab9306a - nlab5320a").attr('opacity',"0.2");
    }
```

The node selector cited above that is working is contained within this same component and, like I said, it is working perfectly. I'm pretty much at my wit's end with this and would appreciate any advice or help. I will be happy to revise my question as needed if more code is required.

So I even tried this ...

The source and target are definitely reporting when I click a link. One of the kind respondents below gave me this code:

```
onClickLink = (id) = {
    d3.select("#"+id).attr('opacity',"0.2");
 }
```

which did not work because when I console log the ID it is returning only the source node name and not the full ID listed in the HTML code. So then I tried this:

```
onClickLink = (source, target) = {
    let id = source + "-" + target;
    d3.select("#"+id).attr('opacity',"0.2");
 }
```

and I got "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#80.107.0.217-nlab3328' is not a valid selector." I am looking at the code and the link does indeed have an ID of "80.107.0.217-nlab3328".

Comment: what is the use of the x1,x2,y1,y2 attrs of the path?

Comment: That is how the original component is determining the source and target of the nodes that are linked.

Comment: Nodes have ids and they use the position of the nodes to find out which nodes are linked by this link, they use the nodes to construct the link

Comment: So does this mean I have no way to target the link directly? It has an ID but d3.select("#"+id) will not work.

Comment: I looked at the code of react-d3-graph and it uses the node ids for the link identification, I have't found the source of the strange attributes yet

Comment: I haven't either :(. Please see my edited initial question above. I am becoming convinced that there is absolutely no way to do this.

Comment: from the source code and most likely the doxygen too (docs): All link callbacks have 2 arguments `(source, target)`. Most likely the `this` is set to the DOM node, try `d3.select(this).attr('opacity',"0.2")`, why is in the first example the link id a concat of the 2 node-ids?

Comment: Got it working finally. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY figured this out. Here is what I had to do. The problem was that I was changing the .attr directly instead of going through "style" which is how it's configured in the code. Here's the code that works...

```
onClickLink = (source, target) => {       
   let id = source + "-" + target;      
   d3.select("#"+id).attr('style',"stroke-width: 10; stroke: rgb(0,0,255); opacity: 1; fill: blue;");
```

}

Thanks to all who responded I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

```
handleClick = (id) => {
    d3.select("#"+id).attr('opacity',"0.2");
    }
```

You select by id so there can only be one.

Re-read the docs about d3-selection.

**Edit**

A method to select DOM elements with a '.' in the id.

```js
handler = (source, target) => {
   //var id = "#" + source + "-" + target;
   var id = source + "-" + target;
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   d3.select(e).style('background-color', 'steelblue');
};

handler('80.107.0.217', 'nlab3328');
```

```html
<div id="80.107.0.217-nlab3328">Text</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't work. In the code the ID is listed as "asw-lab9306a - nlab5320a" but in the console.log for ID I got only "asw-lab9306a". Should I remove the spaces in the listed ID to change " - " to "-"?

Comment: @CHays412, I don't know how you set the id of the path and how you can get a different id in the click handler.

Comment: The id="192.168.1.71-asw-labS5328" is there plain as day in the path code and when I do a console.log I get "192.168.1.71". Makes no sense whatsoever. This is why I have been tormented for two weeks on this.

Comment: @CHays412 the link has an id of the 2 node ids (DNS names) that are connected, but the node has an id of the IP address of the node. What is `id` in the click handler and who supplies this `id`?

Comment: Let me check this and get back to you. I just tried hardcoding an ID and running again and it still didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I finally got it working and posted the answer.

Comment: @CHays412 found a way to select the DOM element with the IP address id.